# Simplify sum of complex logs to single real log

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Sometimes, mathematica likes to give me complex results when, e.g, integrating a real valued function. The result might be something like

```
Log[-t - I w] + Log[-t + I w]
```

where `t` and `w` are >0. The question is: How can I automatically convert this to

```
Log[t^2 + w^2]
```

?

The obvious command

```
FullSimplify[Log[-t - I w] + Log[-t + I w],  Assumptions -> {t > 0, w > 0}]
```

does not do anything.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
expr = Log[-t - I w] + Log[-t + I w];

expr // ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] & // 
 Simplify[#, {w > 0, t > 0}] &

(*  Log[t^2 + w^2]  *)
```